# Как сделать слайдер с навигацией-скроллом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу понять, как реализовать подобный слайдер? Кучу плагиов перерыл - не нашел подходящий. Пример слайдера находится здесь https://www.flatstack.com/team/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: куда я только не наводил мышь, навигация скроллом так и не заработала. Работает только навигация колесиком влево/вправо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В двух словах расскажу. В основе реализации данного слайдера лежит плагин скролла tinyscroll https://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar (почитать тут можно). Код работает, вёрстку нужно подшаманить.

**Целиком код не вмещается, поэтому скидываю ссылку:**

```
  [https://jsfiddle.net/Viachaslau/obp7cghv/3/]
```